# Can i set two different cookie for two different countries for the same website

Tags: ssl, cookies

I have a website where I show the cookie consent bar with some message on it. 
I wanted to show a different message to a different country for the same website. Is it possible?

Comment: This question is more appropriate under https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: How important is it to you that the country information is correct?  i.e. how bad is it if you show the message for the wrong country?  There are some ways to tell where a user is from but they are not 100% accurate and it's always possible for the user to fake it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You need to detect country/region by IP address and then open the corresponding consent bar. So you'll need to make a script to get IP address and sort that and then another to display the content according the previous determination.

*Note that your question is not really about security, it would fit more on a different stackexchange site.* /Migrated.